# Secure wp-admin module from other users

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess

I think, that there are good idea to restrict access to wp-admin folder in .htaccess file by using following lines:

```
#file location: /wp-admin/.htaccess
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.1.1.1
```

Where 1.1.1.1 is my ip address.
But the problem is when some of Wordpress plugins using ajax, for example Woocomerce gross plugin.

One of idea is create copy of **admin-ajax.php** file to **admin-ajax-new.php**, and create rule for **$_GET['action']**, for example:

```
$allowed = array('wpmenucart_ajax');
if( !in_array($_REQUEST['action'], $allowed) )
  die('0');
```

And add access only for this file admin-ajax-new.php for all ip addresses.

Or somehow allow access in .htaccess to **admin-ajax.php** file only when referer is my **exam.ple.com** domain.

What will be the best security solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by [mod_setenvif](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html). By using it we can set an environmental variable if referer is example.com. Then just check whether this environmental variable is set and allow it. Deny all other requests.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer example.com trusted=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer www.example.com trusted=yes

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=trusted
allow from 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: So, how will my .htaccess file looks like in wp-admin directory? I need provide an access for all directory for my ip, and allow access for admin-ajax.php file only when referer is my syte domain